# How can my application benefit from temporary tables?

Tags: sql, mysql

I've been reading a little about temporary tables in MySQL but I'm an admitted newbie when it comes to databases in general and MySQL in particular.  I've looked at some examples and the MySQL documentation on how to create a temporary table, but I'm trying to determine just how temporary tables might benefit my applications and I guess secondly what sorts of issues I can run into.  Granted, each situation is different, but I guess what I'm looking for is some general advice on the topic.

I did a little googling but didn't find exactly what I was looking for on the topic.  If you have any experience with this, I'd love to hear about it.

Thanks,
Matt

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Temporary tables are often valuable when you have a fairly complicated SELECT you want to perform and then perform a bunch of queries on that...

You can do something like:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE myTopCustomers
   SELECT customers.*,count(*) num from customers join purchases using(customerID)
   join items using(itemID) GROUP BY customers.ID HAVING num > 10;
```

And then do a bunch of queries against myTopCustomers without having to do the joins to purchases and items on each query.  Then when your application no longer needs the database handle, no cleanup needs to be done.

Almost always you'll see temporary tables used for derived tables that were expensive to create.

Answer (score 11):

First a disclaimer - my job is reporting so I wind up with far more complex queries than any normal developer would.  If you're writing a simple CRUD (Create Read Update Delete) application (this would be most web applications) then you really don't want to write complex queries, and you are probably doing something wrong if you need to create temporary tables.

That said, I use temporary tables in Postgres for a number of purposes, and most will translate to MySQL.  I use them to break up complex queries into a series of individually understandable pieces.  I use them for consistency - by generating a complex report through a series of queries, and I can then offload some of those queries into modules I use in multiple places, I can make sure that different reports are consistent with each other.  (And make sure that if I need to fix something, I only need to fix it once.)  And, rarely, I deliberately use them to force a specific query plan.  (Don't try this unless you really understand what you are doing!)

So I think temp tables are great.  But that said, it is *very* important for you to understand that databases generally come in two flavors.  The first is optimized for pumping out lots of small transactions, and the other is optimized for pumping out a smaller number of complex reports.  The two types need to be tuned differently, and a complex report run on a transactional database runs the risk of blocking transactions (and therefore making web pages not return quickly).  Therefore you generally don't want to avoid using one database for both purposes.

My guess is that you're writing a web application that needs a transactional database.  In that case, you shouldn't use temp tables.  And if you do need complex reports generated from your transactional data, a recommended best practice is to take regular (eg daily) backups, restore them on another machine, then run reports against that machine.

Answer (score 4):

The best place to use temporary tables is when you need to pull a bunch of data from multiple tables, do some work on that data, and then combine everything to one result set.

In MS SQL, Temporary tables should also be used in place of cursors whenever possible because of the speed and resource impact associated with cursors.

Comment: Not sure if the cursor argument works with MySql, but it does with SqlServer.

Comment: Thanks for your input - I'm using some cursors on my project.  I guess I need to look at that too.

Comment: If you do try to eliminate cursors in your project, your first thought should be to eliminate sequential processing altogether. Set-based > temporary tables > cursors (at least for MS SQL). Eliminating cursors doesn't necessarily mean eliminating sequential processing.

Answer (score 3):

If you are new to databases, there are some good books by Joe Kelko that review best practices for ANSI SQL.  [SQL For Smarties](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0123693799) will describe in great detail the use of temp table, impact of indexes, where clauses, etc.  It's a great reference book with in depth detail.

Answer (score 1):

I've used them in the past when I needed to create evaluated data.  That was before the time of views and sub selects in MySQL though and I generally use those now where I would have needed a temporary table.  The only time I might use them is if the evaluated data took a long time to create.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't done them in MySQL, but I've done them on other databases (Oracle, SQL Server, etc).

Among other tasks, temporary tables provide a way for you to create a queryable (and returnable, say from a sproc) dataset that's purpose-built. Let's say you have several tables of figures -- you can use a temporary table to roll those figures up to nice, clean totals (or other math), then join that temp table to others in your schema for final output. (An example of this, in one of my projects, is calculating how many scheduled calls a given sales-related employee must make per week, bi-weekly, monthly, etc.)

I also often use them as a means of "tilting" the data -- turning columns to rows, etc. They're good for advanced data processing -- but only use them when you need to. (My golden rule, as always, applies: If you don't know why you're using *x*, and you don't know how *x* works, then you probably shouldn't use it.)

Generally, I wind up using them most in sprocs, where complex data processing is needed. I'd love to give a concrete example, but mine would be in T-SQL (as opposed to MySQL's more standard SQL), and also they're all client/production code which I can't share. I'm sure someone else here on SO will pick up and provide some genuine sample code; this was just to help you get the gist of what problem domain temp tables address.