# Left join will null in MySQL

Tags: mysql, left-join, relevance

I am looking for a way to create a relative relevance function when looking for values in two (or more) different tables. So I have tables like this

```
table1:

id weight
1  0.1
2  0.15
3  0.12
6  0.21

table2:

id weight
3  0.09
6  0.2
8  0.1
11 0.13
```

I need to get a relevance function from these two tables by merging them. Same row ids will get 10x relevance and rows with ids from only one table will get "weight" relevance.

Here is an intermediate table which I need to get (and my question is HOW to make such a table):

```
id1  weight1  id2  weight2
1    0.1      null null
2    0.15     null null
3    0.12     3    0.09
6    0.21     6    0.2
null null     8    0.1
null null     11   0.13
```

Using this table I can calculate the relevance whatever I need, but the problem is to create such table from these two. Could you help me?

I tried with LEFT JOIN, STRAIGHT_JOIN, LEFT OUTER JOIN, but they make very different results.

Edit: If it matters, I presently envisage the final table to look something like this:

```
id relevance
 1 0.1
 2 0.15
 3 2.1
 6 4.1
 8 0.1
11 0.13
```

Comment: Seeing as LEFT JOIN and LEFT OUTER JOIN are exactly the same thing, that assertion seems highly implausible

Comment: You need a FULL OUTER JOIN, which MySQL does not support, but which can be emulated - although one has to question the wisdom of having two tables which apparently store the same kind of thing.

Comment: @Strawberry These tables are subqueries actually, yes, they are taken from the same table, but with very different "where" part. How can I emulate FULL OUTER JOIN ?

Comment: Out of curiousity, what would the final result look like?

Comment: I think like this https://e-wm.org/i/E20190222-150905-001.png however final relevance function didn't created yet.

Comment: In that case, I suspect that this can be massively simplified

Comment: @Strawberry Could you give me your idea how to simplify this?

Comment: You really need to rethink your schema. Multiple tables storing the same kind of thing is a bad idea.

Comment: @Strawberry I have different words stored in one table and another table stores "vectors" - relativeness between words and documents. table1 (and table2) is actually a set of documents where one specific word exists. So table1 and table2 are different pieces of the same (documents) table, but related to different words. For example word "dog" can be in documents 1,2,3,6 and word "good" in docs 3,6,8,11. I need a set of docs where I have both words "good dog" and only one word appears (only "good" or only "dog").

Comment: I can use longer requests "The fast fox jumps over the lazy dog" and in this case I will have much more document table chunks.

Comment: This sounds like a terrible approach - but hey, it's your funeral.

Comment: If the problem is literally as you describe, then you should probably be conducting FULLTEXT searches on the data. Otherwise, you should, at the very least, store all the words and document references in one table.

Comment: @Strawberry yes, I have a table of words and another table of vectors - two tables are the same for all documents.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to do a FULL OUTER JOIN in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796872/how-to-do-a-full-outer-join-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a few examples :

> ```
> create table Table1 (
>  id int primary key not null,
>  weight decimal(10,2) not null default 0
> );
> ```

> ```
> create table Table2 (
>  id int primary key not null,
>  weight decimal(10,2) not null default 0
> );
> ```

> ```
> insert into Table1 (id, weight) values
>  (1, 0.10)
> ,(2, 0.15)
> ,(3, 0.12)
> ,(6, 0.21)
> ;
> ```

> ```
> insert into Table2 (id, weight) values
>  (3,  0.09)
> ,(6,  0.20)
> ,(8,  0.10)
> ,(11, 0.13)
> ;
> ```

> ```
> select 
> id12.id as id,
> t1.id as id1,
> t1.weight as weight1,
> t2.id as id2,
> t2.weight as weight2
> from (select id from Table1 union select id from Table2) id12
> left join Table1 t1 on t1.id = id12.id
> left join Table2 t2 on t2.id = id12.id
> ;
> ```
>
> ```
> id |  id1 | weight1 |  id2 | weight2
> -: | ---: | ------: | ---: | ------:
>  1 |    1 |    0.10 | null |    null
>  2 |    2 |    0.15 | null |    null
>  3 |    3 |    0.12 |    3 |    0.09
>  6 |    6 |    0.21 |    6 |    0.20
>  8 | null |    null |    8 |    0.10
> 11 | null |    null |   11 |    0.13
> ```

> ```
> select 
> id12.id as id,
> coalesce(t1.weight,0) + coalesce(t2.weight,0) as relevance
> from (select id from Table1 union select id from Table2) id12
> left join Table1 t1 on t1.id = id12.id
> left join Table2 t2 on t2.id = id12.id
> order by id12.id;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | relevance
> -: | --------:
>  1 |      0.10
>  2 |      0.15
>  3 |      0.21
>  6 |      0.41
>  8 |      0.10
> 11 |      0.13
> ```

> ```
> select id, sum(weight) as relevance
> from
> (
>  select id, weight from Table1
>  union all 
>  select id, weight from Table2
> ) q
> group by id
> order by id;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | relevance
> -: | --------:
>  1 |      0.10
>  2 |      0.15
>  3 |      0.21
>  6 |      0.41
>  8 |      0.10
> 11 |      0.13
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=050be8e0c417a7094a01f7f249b33567)*

The 2nd & 3th queries return the same result.
Which is better?
That would depend on how many extra fields and/or extra calculations are required.

Comment: Thx. Btw, notice that one time UNION is used and another time UNION ALL.  It's important to understand the difference.  `UNION` will only return unique records and remove duplicates, while `UNION ALL` merely sticks the results of the queries together.

Comment: I don't need for UNION at all. The initial table for table1 and table2 is the same table contains ALL documents, meanwhile table1 and table2 are just subqueries contains a selected rows from the same table. So my solutions here is replace a subquery with UNION with (select id from docs) subquery. It works good.

Comment: Oh like that. Ok, looks like you know what you're doing. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `FULL OUTER JOIN` for this, e.g.:

```
SELECT t1.id AS id1, t1.weight AS weight1, t2.id AS id2, t2.weight AS weight2
FROM table1 t1 LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
UNION
SELECT t1.id AS id1, t1.weight AS weight1, t2.id AS id2, t2.weight AS weight2
FROM table1 t1 RIGHT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id;
```

Comment: FWIW, I'd prefer to write that this way... `SELECT t1.id id1
     , t1.weight weight1
     , t2.id id2
     , t2.weight weight2
  FROM table1 t1 
  LEFT 
  JOIN table2 t2 
    ON t2.id = t1.id
 UNION
SELECT t1.id id1
     , t1.weight weight1
     , t2.id id2
     , t2.weight weight2
  FROM table2 t2 
  LEFT
  JOIN table1 t1 
    ON t1.id = t2.id;`

Comment: @Strawberry ah okay. Is it just about the readability or performance as well?

Comment: Just readability - conceptually, I find a LEFT JOIN more intuitive

Comment: Ok I tried this, it works, however I think I will need lots of such subqueries to merge by union, since I can have 3 or even more tables (up to 8) and then I have to combine them all each with other one, right? It's 2^8=64 different subqueries... wow.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT id
     , SUM(weight) * CASE WHEN COUNT(*)=1 THEN 1 ELSE 10 END relevance 
  FROM
     ( SELECT id
            , weight 
         FROM table1 
        UNION 
          ALL 
       SELECT id
            , weight 
         FROM table2
     ) x
 GROUP 
    BY id;
+----+-----------+
| id | relevance |
+----+-----------+
|  1 |      0.10 |
|  2 |      0.15 |
|  3 |      2.10 |
|  6 |      4.10 |
|  8 |      0.10 |
| 11 |      0.13 |
+----+-----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use stored procedures and temporary tables to get solution

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetReleavance()
BEGIN
Create TEMPORARY TABLE tmpList ENGINE=MEMORY
SELECT id, weight from t1
union all 
SELECT id, weight from t2
union all 
SELECT id, weight from t3;

select id, sum(weight)* POW(10,COUNT(1)-1) as relevance 
from tmpList 
group by id;

DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tmpList;

END
```

In the procedure creating a temporary table with all id's and weight from different table and get sum(weight) based on id.

Call the stored procedure using

```
CALL GetReleavance()
```

You can make Union all for number of table you want also it will not make major impact on performance.

Comment: OK. But why would we want to do this !?!

Comment: Temporary tables can have index to optimized. `Create Index tmpId on tmpList(id)` on the procedure after creating temporary table will reduce time in group by class

Comment: The link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116423/how-can-my-application-benefit-from-temporary-tables explains more about a temporary table

Comment: OK. And would that fact help us at all? I'm struggling to see how :-(